# The meaning of "by" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

"Fortunately, recycling has gradually increased and by 2005 it had again reached the same figure as in 1990"

Can I replace "by" by "in" ?

Answer (score 1):

The according dictionary entry reads

> ***by** 4 Indicating a deadline or the end of a particular time period:*
>
> I’ve got to do this report by Monday
>
> by now Kelly needed extensive physiotherapy
>
> [(ODO: by)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/by)
>
> **Synonyms:** no later than, in good time for, at, before

So the answer is depending on the context of your sentence. However the sentence talks about a gradual increase of the recycling, thus indicating it might have risen further since 2005. If that's the case and 2005 was the point were it reached the 1990 levels before rising further they are interchangeable.

On the other hand 2005 could just be a general point in time that is referred to and the levels have been reached beforehand. In that case they are not interchangeable in the above sentence.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the meaning is slightly different.  "by 2005" would mean "sometime in 2005 or before" without pinning down an exact time the figure was reached, while "in 2005" would mean that in that year the figure was measured at the same as in 1990.  Subtle difference that might not even register that way to most people.  I would go with which of those was the more accurate read myself but would call them mostly interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

"Fortunately, recycling has gradually increaed and by 2005 it had again reach the same figure as in 1990" I would say that 'by' is not replaceable by 'in' since 'by 2oo5 means from the day of the invention of bicycles to as on 1st Jan o5. In 2oo5 shall mean from 1st Jan o5 onwards till the given date of 2005.

Comment: Where do the bicycles come from?

Comment: My apologies, kindly substitute the term, "the day of the invention of bicycles'' with  " the day of commencement of the process of recycling."

Answer (score 0):

**Probably yes, but they don't always mean the same thing.**

> **By** 2005 it had reached the same figure...

means that it had reached the same figure *in or before 2005*.

> **In** 2005 it had reached the same figure...

means that it had reached the same figure *in 2005 and not before*.

So if the figure was reached in 2005 you can use either, otherwise not.